# How to request operating system to send email?

Tags: c++, qt

How can a Qt C++ app request the OS to send email with a specific subject, body and possibly an attachment(s) files? It should be dispatched using the configured default email client.

Comment: I imagine the user will always be in control of this; if you want to pop open a predefined message (that the user must send manually), you can use a `mailto:` URL and then ask the system to open that URL like any other.  The URL format allows you to embed a subject and body, and mail clients *usually* respect those.  Auto-setting attachments is a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small component that handles attachments too. It creates a temporary .eml file filled with the content that you provide to the Email class and opens the default email client with openInDefaultProgram(). The API should be self explaining, but if you have any problems, please don't hesitate to contact me :)

https://github.com/picaschaf/qt-email

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [`QDesktopServices::openUrl()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) will accept a `mailto:` URL.  But specifying an attachment could be tricky.